# Is it bad practice to do "small_table LEFT JOIN large_table"?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm connecting to a database which I cannot administer and I wrote a query which did a left join between two tables - one small and one several orders of magnitude larger. At some point, the database returned this error:

> Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_some_table.MYI'; try to repair it

I contacted the administrators and I was told that I'm getting this error because I'm doing the left join incorrectly, that I should NEVER left join a small table to a large table and that I should reverse the join order. The reason they gave was that when done my way, MySQL will try to create a temp table which is too large and query will fail. Their solution fails elsewhere, but that's not important here.

I found their explanation odd, so I ran explain on my query:

```
           id = '1'
  select_type = 'SIMPLE'
        table = 'small_table'
         type = 'ALL'
possible_keys = NULL
          key = NULL
      key_len = NULL
          ref = NULL
         rows = '23'
        Extra = 'Using temporary; Using filesort'

           id = '1'
  select_type = 'SIMPLE'
        table = 'large_table'
         type = 'ref'
possible_keys = 'ID,More'
          key = 'ID'
      key_len = '4'
          ref = 'their_db.small_table.ID'
         rows = '41983'
        Extra = NULL
```

(The 41983 rows in the second table are not very interesting to me, I just needed the latest record, which is why my query has `order by large_table.ValueDateTime desc limit 1` at the end.)

I was careful enough to do a select by columns which the admins themselves told me, should hold unique values (and thus I assumed indexed), but it seems they haven't indexed those columns.

My question is - is doing the join the way I did ('small_table LEFT JOIN large_table') bad practice in general, or can such queries be made to execute successfully with proper indexing?

Edit:
Here's what the query looks like (this is not the actual query, but similar):

```
select large_table.ValueDateTime as LastDate,
       small_table.DeviceIMEI as IMEI,
       small_table.Other_Columns as My_Names,
       large_table.Pwr as Voltage,
       large_table.Temp as Temperature
from small_table left join large_table on small_table.ID = large_table.ID
where DeviceIMEI = 500
order by ValueDateTime desc
limit 1;
```

Basically what I'm doing is trying to get the most current data for a device, given that Voltage and Temperature change over time. The DeviceIMEI, ID and ValueDateTime should be unique, but aren't indexed (like I said earlier, I don't administer the database, I only have read permissions).

Edit 2:

**Please focus on answering my actual question, not on attempting to rewrite my original query.**

Comment: Another example why MySQL is ALMOST a good RDMS... And I can't believe that admin could said something soooo stupid: "reverse join order". Yeah, sure.

Comment: Nikola, how many rows do you get withouth this `limit 1`?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek If I remove the limit 1, I get 200652 rows in result.

Comment: Then you are definitiely not joining on unique conditions - there should be no more rows then there are in large_table + small_table - 1.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek Like I said, "but it seems they haven't indexed those columns".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left join thing is a red herring.

It is however an actual problem of running out of space for temp tables. But the order of your join makes no difference. The only thing that matters is how many rows MySQL must work with.

Which brings me to the LIMIT command:

Here is the problem:

It order to get the single row you asked for, MySQL has to sort the ENTIRE record set, then grab the top one. In order to sort it, it must store it - either in memory or on disk. And that's where you are running out of space. Every single column you requested get stored on disk, for the entire table, then sorted.

This is slow, very slow, and uses a lot of disk space.

Solutions:

You want MySQL to be able to use an index for the sorting. But in your query it can't. It's using an index for the join reference, and MySQL can only use one index per query.

Do you even have an index on the sort column? Try that first.

Another option is to do a separate query, where you select just the ID of the large table, LIMIT 1. Then the temporary table is MUCH smaller since all it has are IDs without all the other columns.

Once you know the ID then retrieve all the columns you need directly from the tables. You can do this in one shot with a subquery. If you post your query I could rewrite it to show you, but it's basically `ID = (SELECT ID FROM ..... LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Like I said, I don't administer the database and I can't add indexes. I have only the read permissions. Also, the order of the join DOES make a difference. The query doesn't result in error, but the problem then is that if a device has made no records in large_table, then there is nothing to left join onto the data in small_table which does, in fact, contain a record of such a device. The admin told me to do that in two separate queries, but doing it that way just complicates applications which use the database unnecessarily IMHO. Also, I've updated my question to add the query.

Comment: It works without the LEFT not because there is some issue with left joins, but because you are sorting on a column in the right table. But what happens if the right table is blank (missing)? How should it sort? What happens is that it's not able to just look in the large table and directly find the most recent date - that might not be the correct row, since it's possible the correct row will have no record in the large table, and only in the small table. So it must actually calculate everything, and then sort.

Comment: So tell me, what do you expect for blank rows in the large table? How should it sort? Why do you need the left join? You'll never actually get record from the small table, that are missing a record on the large table, because you are sorting by a value on the large table and getting only one of them. Missing rows will never show up.

Comment: Which is exactly what happens, like I wrote in my comment, and like I told the admins, to which they said I should use two separate queries (not a sub-query, but two separate queries). I've been having problems with the way their database is designed for ages now, this is just the latest thing to add to the pile of junk I've been getting from them (which is why I'm going to have my own database now). This comment that my way of doing the left join is bad practice just got me so stumped, I had to ask.

Comment: I don't get why you even need the left join - it's not making any difference to the final result, so why do you want it? BTW having full access to the database wouldn't help you here - you would still run into this issue.

Comment: I don't want it, I'm asking if it's bad practice (which you answered with "no") and if it can still execute successfully with proper indexing on systems where resources are limited (i.e. if creating indexes could reduce the size of the temp table which is created in any significant way, which you didn't answer). You DID suggest I create an index, but I can't, because I can't administer the database as I only have read permissions. Why did you suggest that? Would that reduce/eliminate the temporary?

Comment: If your query is fast without the LEFT JOIN, I suspect you already have an index. But the index can't be used with a left join. Post the explain for the query without the left join. Left joins are NOT bad practice - except in this one specific case you managed to hit upon - a left join, but you sort with the right table. And even that is not practice if you only have a limited result set to sort, i.e. the index is used for row selection, not sorting. It's only when you have a HUGE amount to sort that you have an issue.

Comment: I thought that if I had an index on two columns in large table, namely (ID, ValueDateTime), then left join could use that index to search through rows directly, and immediately write into the result set - and since there's a `limit 1` in there, it would immediately complete, making the whole thing O(log(n)), where n is the number of records in the large table (number of records in the small table is negligible). But if it can't use an index in that way, then it can't use an index in that way. Thanks for the info.

Comment: That would work if those were the only rows (i.e. not left join). The trouble is that there could be rows from the small table with no match in the right one. And because there are extra rows the index is not definitive and MySQL won't use it.